# Deserializing XML time to datetime?

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I Have a third party XML file that I need to deserialize into objects but when I do so I get an error: `string was not recognized as a valid datetime`. This is because the time in XML is just that a time, in the format `HH:mm:SS` and the classes that were Generated from the XSD from the third party produce a `datetime` field that expects a date time not just a time.

they give me the xml:

```
<PO>
...
<PurchaseOrderTime>8:00:00</PurchaseOrderTime>
...
</PO>
```

The Generated class creates a `System.DateTime` object to hold the deserialized PurchaseOrderTime but fails due to it expecting a format along the lines of `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:SS tt` but as I have no control over what they send me xsd or xml, what can I do to fix this?

Is there a way to pre-process the field to get what I need?

Do I have to manually change the `System.DateTime` to a `timespan`(there is more than just this one time field otherwise I would have just done that)

What is the best way to do this?

**Edit 1:**
Here is the generated class from the XSD

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.1015")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.spscommerce.com/RSX")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("OrderHeader", Namespace="http://www.spscommerce.com/RSX", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class OrderHeaderType : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        ...

        private System.DateTime purchaseOrderTimeField;

        private bool purchaseOrderTimeFieldSpecified;

        ...

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="time", Order=7)]
        public System.DateTime PurchaseOrderTime {
            get {
                return this.purchaseOrderTimeField;
            }
            set {
                if ((purchaseOrderTimeField.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.purchaseOrderTimeField = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("PurchaseOrderTime");
                }
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool PurchaseOrderTimeSpecified {
            get {
                return this.purchaseOrderTimeFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                if ((purchaseOrderTimeFieldSpecified.Equals(value) != true)) {
                    this.purchaseOrderTimeFieldSpecified = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("PurchaseOrderTimeSpecified");
                }
            }
        }


        #region Serialize/Deserialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes current OrderHeaderType object into an XML document
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serialize() {
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try {
                memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally {
                if ((streamReader != null)) {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null)) {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes workflow markup into an OrderHeaderType object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xml">string workflow markup to deserialize</param>
        /// <param name="obj">Output OrderHeaderType object</param>
        /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
        /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
        public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out OrderHeaderType obj, out System.Exception exception) {
            exception = null;
            obj = default(OrderHeaderType);
            try {
                obj = Deserialize(xml);
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) {
                exception = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out OrderHeaderType obj) {
            System.Exception exception = null;
            return Deserialize(xml, out obj, out exception);
        }

        public static OrderHeaderType Deserialize(string xml) {
            System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
            try {
                stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
                return ((OrderHeaderType)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
            }
            finally {
                if ((stringReader != null)) {
                    stringReader.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes xml markup from file into an OrderHeaderType object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName">string xml file to load and deserialize</param>
        /// <param name="obj">Output OrderHeaderType object</param>
        /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
        /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
        public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out OrderHeaderType obj, out System.Exception exception) {
            exception = null;
            obj = default(OrderHeaderType);
            try {
                obj = LoadFromFile(fileName);
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) {
                exception = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out OrderHeaderType obj) {
            System.Exception exception = null;
            return LoadFromFile(fileName, out obj, out exception);
        }

        public static OrderHeaderType LoadFromFile(string fileName) {
            System.IO.FileStream file = null;
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
            try {
                file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
                string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
                file.Close();
                return Deserialize(xmlString);
            }
            finally {
                if ((file != null)) {
                    file.Dispose();
                }
                if ((sr != null)) {
                    sr.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: How do you deserialize the XML?

Comment: I used XSD2Code to generate the classes from the xml and it `automagically` adds serialize and deserialize methods will edit question with the methods soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Ended up doing a few things,

1. I used a refactoring tool to change all `DateTime`s in the generated classes to strings and and wrote the code in a way that it would work as if the `DateTime` was a string. (while this may not be optimal it works!)
2. Asked the people who generated the xml to fix the generated xml file. so that when/if I get a new file I can just regenerate the classes from the XSD and use the `DateTime` fields as expected.

While programing around this issue with strings was not the best thing, It should work either way and until I get a file that processes correctly I will just use the refactoring tool to change all `DateTime`'s to strings.

Answer (score -1):

If your user gives you a document which does not validate against the schema, XSD2Code is likely to have trouble with it. Throw it back at the user and tell them to fix it. Or parse the document and interpret it yourself, so you can write your own code to decide how to recover from questionable cases.

If the document does validate against the schema but XSD2Code can't handle it, complain to the authors of XSD2Code and get it fixed, or replace it with something which doesn't have the same bug/limitation. Which may, again, mean writing your own code.

If XSD2Code can handle it but C#'s provided code can't, you need to either go looking for code that can handle it (suggested websearch: c# parse iso 8601), or write your own.

Comment: The XML does validate against the XSD. It's just that C# doesn't like the format the time comes in as. I wish they were users and I could tell them to just fix it but they are the ones dictating what the XML and XSD are, in this case I'm the user.

Comment: Is your issue that the code XSD2Code is generating doesn't accept the expected range of [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) date/time syntaxes, or that the C# datetime class doesn't do so?

If the former, you need to take it up with the folks who wrote XSD2Code. Though they may blame it on the latter.

If the latter, you or they need to find or write a routine which can handle this.

Comment: It's the latter, C# datetime class doesn't accept the expected time format.

Comment: Websearch "c# parse iso 8601" seems to find some promising code. I've no experience with them (not really a c# user) so I can't advise beyond that. Updated my answer.